# Change parent background colour based on HTML element value

Tags: jquery

Sorry for the newb question, I haven't coded in a long time and trying to help a friend out. His website feeds back from an API so he has no control over the format, the following HTML:

```
<div class="storeList">
<span class="newStore">W5 5RN</span>
<span class="nearestStore">HARLESDEN<span class="mileage"><span class="mileCount">4</span> miles</span></span>
<span class="nearestStore">BURNT OAK<span class="mileage"><span class="mileCount">9</span> miles</span></span>
<span class="nearestStore">EDGEWARE<span class="mileage"><span class="mileCount">11</span> miles</span></span>
<span class="nearestStore">UXBRIDGE<span class="mileage"><span class="mileCount">12</span> miles</span></span>
<span class="nearestStore">NEW MALDEN<span class="mileage"><span class="mileCount">12</span> miles</span></span>
</div>
<div class="storeList">
<span class="newStore">W6 8RN</span>
<span class="nearestStore">HARLESDEN<span class="mileage"><span class="mileCount">2</span> miles</span></span>
<span class="nearestStore">BURNT OAK<span class="mileage"><span class="mileCount">5</span> miles</span></span>
<span class="nearestStore">EDGEWARE<span class="mileage"><span class="mileCount">7</span> miles</span></span>
<span class="nearestStore">UXBRIDGE<span class="mileage"><span class="mileCount">14</span> miles</span></span>
<span class="nearestStore">NEW MALDEN<span class="mileage"><span class="mileCount">16</span> miles</span></span>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is after the API has displayed the data, to loop through each of the results with the class .storeList and check each child element of 'mileCount' and display three different background colours to the parent element of .nearestStore with jQuery depending if the mileage is 0-3 miles (red), 3-5 miles (yellow) over 5 miles (green).

I know I've got to do an each statement but from there, I'm lost. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you:

```
$('.mileCount').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    miles = $this.text(),
    color;
  if (miles < 3) {
    color = 'red';
  } else if (miles >= 3 && miles <= 5) {
    color = 'yellow';
  } else if (miles > 5) {
    color = 'green';
  }

 $this.parents('.nearestStore').css('color', color);

});
```

Loop through each `span` containing the miles, set the color accordingly and then change the color of the parent element `.nearestStore`

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/7dne75nq/)

You could also loop through `.nearestStore` and search for the child-element `.mileCount` get the text and set the color of the element itself.

Comment: Thank you - it was posted first and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```js
$('.mileCount').each(function() {
   var count = parseInt($(this).text());
   $(this).parents('.nearestStore').css('background-color', ((count > 5) ? 'green' : (count > 3) ? 'yellow': 'red'));
});
```

```html
<div class="storeList">
<span class="newStore">W5 5RN</span>
<span class="nearestStore">HARLESDEN<span class="mileage"><span class="mileCount">4</span> miles</span></span>
<span class="nearestStore">BURNT OAK<span class="mileage"><span class="mileCount">9</span> miles</span></span>
<span class="nearestStore">EDGEWARE<span class="mileage"><span class="mileCount">11</span> miles</span></span>
<span class="nearestStore">UXBRIDGE<span class="mileage"><span class="mileCount">12</span> miles</span></span>
<span class="nearestStore">NEW MALDEN<span class="mileage"><span class="mileCount">12</span> miles</span></span>
</div>
<div class="storeList">
<span class="newStore">W6 8RN</span>
<span class="nearestStore">HARLESDEN<span class="mileage"><span class="mileCount">2</span> miles</span></span>
<span class="nearestStore">BURNT OAK<span class="mileage"><span class="mileCount">5</span> miles</span></span>
<span class="nearestStore">EDGEWARE<span class="mileage"><span class="mileCount">7</span> miles</span></span>
<span class="nearestStore">UXBRIDGE<span class="mileage"><span class="mileCount">14</span> miles</span></span>
<span class="nearestStore">NEW MALDEN<span class="mileage"><span class="mileCount">16</span> miles</span></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Edit: I removed the unnecessary stuff...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this js,

```
   $( ".mileCount" ).each(function( index ) {
  if(parseInt($(this).text())<='3')
    {     
       $(this).addClass('red');
    }else if(parseInt($(this).text())>'3' && parseInt($(this).text())<='5'){
      $(this).addClass('blue');
    }
    else{
      $(this).addClass('orange');
  }
});
```

This would add a class to every span that matches your code, Workable code here in this pen:

http://codepen.io/dragonclaw/pen/RooxMJ

hope it helps.